# Heroku is deploying old react?

Tags: reactjs, laravel, heroku

Im using laravel framework (as rest api) and reactjs (to render views). I did a lot of changes to my code (local) and then pushed it on github and deploy on heroku. I noticed that react app is rendering old code version when laravel api works fine (i can use routes which i added). Why react didnt update?

package.json:

```
{
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "npm run development",
        "development": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "watch": "npm run development -- --watch",
        "watch-poll": "npm run watch -- --watch-poll",
        "hot": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "prod": "npm run production",
        "production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --no-progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"
    },
    "devDependencies": {},
    "dependencies": {
        "axios": "^0.18",
        "babel-preset-react": "^6.23.0",
        "cross-env": "^5.1",
        "jquery": "^3.2",
        "laravel-mix": "^2.0",
        "lodash": "^4.17.4",
        "popper.js": "^1.12",
        "react": "^16.2.0",
        "react-dom": "^16.2.0",
        "gh-pages": "^2.0.1",
        "react-icons": "^3.2.2",
        "react-redux": "^5.0.7",
        "react-scripts": "1.1.5",
        "redux": "^4.0.0",
        "styled-components": "^4.0.2",
        "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
        "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0"
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a command like `npm run build` you need to run, to build the production assets? Check the `scripts` section of `package.json`.

Answer (score 0):

May be the problem with your browser cache. Not in heroku. Please clear your browser cache and open your app again

Comment: I cleared brower cache, and I rename 1 api route on home page and react is trying to fetch old one (im 100% sure that i changed it in react config).

Answer (score 0):

Okay i figured it out! I need to render project on localhost to regenerate app.js in public/js before deploy on heroku -_-'

Comment: FYI, you can make this happen automatically. Add `"postinstall": "npm run production"` to your `scripts` section of your `package.json`. That will make Heroku automatically build everything as part of a deploy. See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#customizing-the-build-process